# Can I use PNG instead of SVG for icons?

Tags: icons, gimp, inkscape, png, svg

I'm making a theme. I'm new to the whole linux/ ubuntu thing. I have a lot of experience using photoshop/ gimp so drawing up some icons in those programs is a piece of cake to me. I was messing around with the theming in and I discovered that alot of the icons use SVGs. So I assumed that I had to download Inkscape and remake my icons. I really don't like using Inkscape though, plus I just don't want to go through learning how to use another art program all over again. So how exactly do I replace SVG icons with the PNGs I made?

I'm using Linux Mint 14, but I figured I'd ask here as it seems I'd get more support and seeing that Mint and Ubuntu are very similar.

I remember seeing something on a thread not to long ago that SVGs tax the cpu and graphics more than PNGs. That true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVGs do not use any more CPU to render than PNGs do.

You can however, use PNGs if you wish instead of SVGs. Regardless of which you choose, you need to draw the icons at various different sizes to get the best results.

Comment: So how exactly do I replace them with PNGs? Last time I tried copying over folder.png to replace folder.svg and all it did was just paste into the folder. Or if I open up the icon in gimp and export it as png... same thing. right clicking on the icon and going to properties and switching out the icon there doesn't work either. I'm editing the main theme, not making a new one from scratch(should of said that). I'm just trying to replace everything with my own icons.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you want a theme made with PNGs, just get rid of the SVG files and only have the PNG files in it, such as `48x48/mimetypes/text-plain.png`. You don't need both.

Comment: Got it thanks. Sorry I complicate my questions.